# Referencing Page.Title after it has been set as part of a asp:contentplaceholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, master-pages

I've got a master page setup with a contentplaceholder control inside the title tag as so:

```
<head id="head1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 9pt; }
    </style>

    <title><asp:contentplaceholder id="title" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
```

That contentplaceholder is implemented inside a page that uses that masterpage as so:

```
<asp:content runat="server" contentplaceholderid="title">
    Welcome: <%= this.BasketID %>
</asp:content>
```

I'm trying to then get a copy of the substituted title inside the masterpage body (also tried inside the page - and this doesnt work either) like:

```
<p>
    <strong>Subject:</strong> <%# Page.Title %>
</p>
```

In all cases `Page.Title` and `Page.Header.Title` are `""` (I've tried both databinding and using the `<%= %>` syntax to no avail.

Does anyone know what is going on here and how I can overcome this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're getting is because you are 'tricking' the page cycle. You'd better use this in the codebehind of the page:

```
Master.Title = "Welcome: " + basketId
```

You could do it this way however; on the masterpage: create a HtmlTextWriter, configure it to write to a MemoryStream. Render the 'title' contentplaceholder to the HtmlTextWriter, attach a StreamReader to the stream to grab the content as a string, and output this to your page. Yet, this is not efficient, and way too much work :-)

Comment: I thought I must have been doing something 'out of order', its these little things that drive me mad about WebForms sometimes! :) Thanks for the advice.